# "Insufficient Entropy (CWE ID 331)" in com.google.android.gms.analytics while using veracode

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, veracode

When used **VERACODE** got *Insufficient Entropy* for using java.util.Random.nextInt in Android application.
In my app source code **Random.nextInt** was not used, it's used in google analytics (com.google.android.gms.analytics)

**Attack Vector :** java.util.Random.nextInt

**Description :** Standard random number generators do not provide a sufficient amount of entropy when used for security purposes. Attackers can brute force the amount of pseudorandom number generators such as rand().

Comment: what is your problem . Make your question explicit

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a commercial tool to check for potential security vulnerabilities.

GoogleAnalytics is closed-source, so it is difficult to be sure how it using `Random`.  Hence, it is difficult to know if this is significant, or whether there is a workaround.

However, the report you are getting is very non-specific.  Yes, Random is a poor choice if the GoogleAnalytics functionality requires a good source of "randomness".  But we don't know if that is the case.  It might simply be using the random number generator for choosing the google analytics server that it talks to ... for load balancing.

If this is a real worry to you:

1. Contact the Veracode manufacturer for a clarification of what the report means.  They may be able to tell you that this is a false alarm.
2. Contact Google and ask them if there is a real vulnerability.